# My family member has never flown, wondering if someone can meet him at his layover and lead him to his next plane

Tags: air-travel, solo-travel, atlanta

He has a layover in atlanta which is stressfull for anyone but its only 52 minutes and he has never been on a plane or in an airport, can someone meet him off the plane and lead him to his next gate so he doesnt get lost and miss his flight??

Comment: It's not really that confusing to navigate, it's just very crowded. Does he have some particular special needs?

Comment: Are you looking for you / a family member to go airside to help? Or are you looking to hire someone / a service to do it? Or are you just wondering about free assistance?

Comment: There is a high-end service in Atlanta who will meet at the door of the plane and accompany them though baggage, connections, etc. It's rather pricey, is that something you would consider?

Comment: Is he flying domestically or arriving on an international flight? I've done a tight layover like that on Delta from South Africa, connecting to LAX. Train wasn't running so we had to walk (quickly) a good distance besides getting through immigration and customs.

Answer (score 5):

If your family member is elderly or if he is a minor, then you can arrange some options for him.  But if he is a fully functional adult, then he is pretty much on his own.

Atlanta is not that difficult of an airport to navigate, but it can be crowded.  Assuming he is flying Delta, they usually have someone at the gate to direct passengers to their next flight and they would be happy to give him detail instructions of getting to his next gate.  And there are often information people at the train stations to assist people with finding their way.

Personally I would have booked him flights with a longer layover, as 52 minutes is tight, but still do-able.

Comment: Second the time bit!  I certainly wouldn't book a 52 minute layover for a virgin traveler!  I'd only book it for myself if there wasn't any other reasonable option.